Error "invalid frame header when creating connection between Spring boot and Vue.js
I'm trying to develop a Spring boot project and I want to use Vue to handle the frontend. But when I ran the Vue project I always got the error WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.31.105:3000/ws' failed: Invalid frame header.
I have logged some debugs:
WebSocket connection established // from Login.vue
WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.31.105:3000/ws' failed: Invalid frame header
WebSocketClient @ WebSocketClient.js:13
initSocket @ socket.js:27
eval @ index.js:320
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=192.168.31.105&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=false @ chunk-vendors.js:172
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:239
(anonymous) @ app.js:401
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:275
(anonymous) @ app.js:403
(anonymous) @ app.js:405Understand this error
LoginUser.vue:86 Message from server: Server received: Hello from client!

I found out that the connection between Spring boot and Vue was still established successfully and it still send the message from client but I don't know why I still get the error Invalid frame header.
There are my config :
Login.vue:
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 200px;">
      <form @submit.prevent="login" id="loginForm">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Enter the account:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" v-model="username" required="required"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Enter the password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" required="required"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" class="button-green"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" id="token" value="">

<!--        <p style="text-align: left">Or login with admin account <span><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin_login"-->
<!--                                                class="button-green">Admin login</a> </span></p>-->
      </form>
    </div>
    <p>Haven't got an account?</p>
<!--    <a href="/register" id="register-link">Register</a>-->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'LoginUser',
  data() {
    return {
      username : '',
      password : '',
      socket: null,
      messages: [] 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login" , {
          method : 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username : this.username,
            password : this.password
          })
        })
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Login error");
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.token) {
          console.log("Token :" + data.token);
        }
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
   ,
    sendMessage(message) {
      if (this.socket && this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        this.socket.send(message); 
      } else {
        console.error('WebSocket is not open');
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.title = 'My login page';
        this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws');
    this.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection established');
      this.sendMessage('Hello from client!');
    };
    this.socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log('Message from server:', event.data);
      this.messages.push(event.data);  // Lưu tin nhắn vào mảng
    };

    this.socket.onclose = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
    };


    this.socket.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };
  }
}
</script>

vue.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/ws': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',  // Proxy for WebSocket server on Spring Boot
                changeOrigin: true,
                ws: true
            }
        },
        hot: false,  
        liveReload: false  
    }
});

My WebSocketHandler.java:
public class MyWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("WebSocket connection established: " + session.getId());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getPayload());
       
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Server received: " + message.getPayload()));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("WebSocket connection closed: " + session.getId());
    }
}

WebSocketConfig.java:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myWebSocketHandler(), "/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://192.168.31.105:3000");  // 
    }

    @Bean
    public MyWebSocketHandler myWebSocketHandler() {
        return new MyWebSocketHandler();
    }
}

